# Anyone found a Cocoa Touch library for integrating Bing Maps into an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, bing-maps

I ran across VirtualEarthKit at http://consonancesw.com/developers/virtualearthkit/faq.php but so far they only have a wrapper for OS X and not iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has launched Bing SDK for iPhone and Mac both. 
Visit [iBing-CodePlex][1]
  [1]: http://ibing.codeplex.com/ .

(Feel Free To Vote The Answer If You Find It Helpful :) )

Comment: Thanks, although unfortunately as far as I can tell, this sdk is only for web, image, and video search and does not include the maps api (yet?).